# I have an issue with importing data to asp.net page , when i open the page i finde all the filed empty

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
 // this the code of the linked database with page 

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["IDContent"]))

        {
            Response.Redirect("ContentList.aspx");
        }

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["IDContent"]))
        {

            if (!IsPostBack)
```

//here is the connectionString

```
            {
                SqlConnection Cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = Lenovo;Initial Catalog = Web_Data; Integrated Security = True");
                Cn.Open();

                string Sql = "Select * From Content_Table Where IDContent = @IDContent";
                DataTable Dt = new DataTabel();
                SqlDataAdapter Da = new SqlDataAdapter(Sql, Cn);

                Da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("IDContent", Request.QueryString["IDContent"]);
                Da.Fill(Dt);
                Cn.Close();
```

//code for importing data from Sql server

```
                 if (Dt.Rows.Count > 0)

                {
                    TxtCategory2.SelectedValue = Dt.Rows[0]["FIDContent"].ToString();
                    TxtTitel2.Text = Dt.Rows[0]["ContentTitel"].ToString();
                    TxtDateTime2.Text = Dt.Rows[0]["ContentDateTime"].ToString();
                    TxtSummary2.Text = Dt.Rows[0]["ContentSummary"].ToString();
                    TextImage.Text = Dt.Rows[0]["ContentImage"].ToString();
                    TxtText2.Text = Dt.Rows[0]["ContentText"].ToString();

                    Image1.ImageUrl = TextImage.Text;

                }
                else
                {

                    LbMsg2.Text = " The Content is not exist!";
                }

                }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you see an exception or you see the message " The Content is not exist!";

Comment: No Actually i'm importing Data when the page load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find that there is wrong in the Spelling of "IDContent" and i Change it to "ContentID" like the same name on the SQL Server Table and it is work!, this is just typing erorr.